# Правильно выбрать лексическую единицу

Tags: лексика

Как правильно: развитой  художественный вкус  либо развитый? Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Совсем недавно было нормой только *развитóй* — достигший высокой степени развития — развитóй вкус и духовно зрелый, просвещённый и культурный («развитóй юноша»). Это прилагательное. Акцент на окончании указывал на принадлежность к имени прилагательному. И причастие *развúтый* («развúтая верёвка»).

Например, форма «рáзвитый» (ребенок) как прилагательное снабжается запретительной пометой в словаре-справочнике под редакцией Р.И. Аванесова и С.И. Ожегова,  хотя, как убедительно доказывает С.Н. Борунова, в современном русском языке, «когда произошла стилистическая нейтрализация приставки раз-, стало возможно префиксальное ударение в причастии и прилагательном». Как отмечает Н.С. Валгина, в картотеке Института русского языка зафиксированы в прилагательных оба ударения: НОРМАТИВНОЕ – *развитой* и ненормативное, возможное как разговорное,— *развитый*. Возможно, нормативность флективного ударения в 60 – 70-е годы во многом стимулировалась частотностью употребления официальных терминологических сочетаний типа «развитóй социализм». Современный материал свидетельствует о расширении употребительности префиксального ударения у прилагательного, и потому его можно признать вариантом нормы при **предпочтительном** варианте *развитóй*.

Не варьируется ударение лишь в причастии *развúтый* («развúтая веревка» ) и в сложных прилагательных («слаборáзвитый») .

Прилагательные «развитой» и «развитый» в качестве одиночных определений нормативно равноценны, хотя в определительных оборотах предпочтительнее оказывается форма прилагательного с приставочным ударением.

Так что предпочтительно сказать *развитóй художественный вкус*, но: *вкус, рáзвитый с детства*. А вообще, оба варианта — норма.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве одиночных определений возможно оба варианта,хотя в определительных оборотах предпочтительне оказывается форма прилагательного с приставочным ударением - "экономически развитый район".

Answer (score 1):

Современный глагол развить имеет два значения: а) Раскрутить что-л. свитое, завитое, скрученное,  развИтый; б) достигнуть определенной стадии развития, развитОй (прил.) и рАзвитый/развИтый (причастие). Второе значение  более позднее, и оно соотнесено с существительным "развитие", которое появилось в языке в 18 веке и является словообразовательной калькой с немецкого языка.

Две формы развитОй и рАзвитый  фактически конкурируют между собой, и их значение определяется довольно противоречиво. В орфоэпических словарях развитОй (прил) - достигший значительной степени совершенства, а рАзвитый/развИтый - причастие: рАзвитая нами деятельность, рАзвитые в умственном отношении. Так как различные уровни развития, а также достижение предела здесь определить сложно, то остается формальное решение по наличию зависимых слов:"едва развИтый жизни цвет", рАзвитый в художественном отношении вкус - причастие, "развитОй" вкус - прилагательное.

Но всем эти словарным статьям противоречит практика. В Нацкорпусе форма "развитой" редко встречается в современной литературе  и вытесняется формой "развитый" во всех значениях. Интернет формы "развитОй вкус" и "развитОй человек" просто не узнает.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Современная литература

Но для ее понимания нужен развитый вкус, нужно чутье художника. [И. А. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы (1959)  Вот вы ― умный, развитый человек...Александр Клейн. Виктор Шендерович // «Пятое измерение», 2002]. Это был идеально сложенный и гармонически развитый человек. [Владимир Войнович. Москва 2042 (1986)]

XIX век

Ни один развитой человек не раскроет вашей книги и не скажет вам спасибо за ваше эпическое спокойствие.. [Д. И. Писарев. (1861)] "А так как развитой человек не может минуты прожить без разговора..."(М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин)

Comment: На Грамота.ру поступил такой вопрос.  Как сейчас употребляются прилагательное РАЗВИТОЙ ( развитАя экономика, развитЫе страны, развитАя сеть дорог...) и причастие РАЗВИТЫЙ ( рАзвитая нами идея)? Насколько неукоснительно соблюдаются рекомендации по их разграничению? Может, наблюдается тенденция к расширению сферы употребления этого слова с ударением на первый слог? Например: "человек с хорошо рАзвитой мускулатурой" или только "человек с хорошо развитОй мускулатурой"7 Спасибо. Людмила.
Пичугова Людмила Николаевна

Comment: Ответ справочной службы русского языка

    В значении «получивший развитие» возможны оба варианта: _рАзвИтая экономика, рАзвИтая нами идея_. В значении «достигший значительного физического развития» употребляется _развитОй_.

Только не совсем ясен ответ справки: "Возможны оба варианта". Каких варианта:  в ударении или два варианта: прилагательное и причастие?